# Python invalid syntax for try/except

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an exception based on whether or not a file has been removed:

```
def remove_file():
    print("Removing the output file: ", output_file)
    try:
        os.remove(output_file)
    except RemoveFileError,e:
        remove_stat = e.returncode
    if remove_stat == 0:
        print("File Removed!")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 198
    except RemoveFileError,e:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought I could call the exception whatever I wanted. Is that not the case? How can I write this correctly?

Comment: You used Python 2 syntax in Python 3. → `except RemoveFileError as e:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Python are you using? Because the syntax has changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

In Python 2, it's (mostly) `except Exception, var:` where it is `except Exception as var:` in Python 3.

Notice that Python 3 syntax was backported to Python 2.6 and 2.7, so it is not unusual to see `except Exception as var` in those versions (and this should be preferred if you want this specific piece of code to work on both Python 2.6+ and 3+).